What are the minimum and maximum values of the given expression?
What are the maximum and minimum values of $$f(x,y,z)=x^{2}-5y+3z^{2}$$ ?
Where $x\in [1,7]$ ; $y\in (1,7]$ ; $z\in [1,7)$
I found one hint for this question.
I assumed the maximum values of {$x,y,z$} for finding the maximum value of $f(x,y,z)$ and I assumed the minimum values of {$a,b,c$} for finding the minimum value of $f(x,y,z)$.
I took into consideration the given values of {$x,y,z$} to be $x\in [1,7]$ ; $y\in [1,7]$ ; $z\in [1,7]$
Therefore the minimum value of $f(x,y,z)$ is $$f(1,1,1)=1^{2}-5(1)+3(1^{2})$$
$$\implies f(1,1,1)=-1$$
And the maximum value of $f(x,y,z)$ is $$f(7,7,7)=7^{2}-5(7)+3(7^{2})$$
$$\implies f(7,7,7)=161$$
Therefore I can write the following inequality.
$$-1<f(x,y,z)<161$$
$$\implies -1<x^{2}-5y+3z^{2}<161$$
But here we can't say that the maximum value of $f(x,y,z)$ is $161$ and the minimum value of $f(x,y,z)$ is $-1$.
For $-1$ to be the minimum and $161$ to be the maximum the inequality will be
$$-1\leq f(x,y,z)\leq 161$$
$$\implies -1\leq x^{2}-5y+3z^{2}\leq 161$$
Also the conditions are $x\in [1,7] $ ; $y\in (1,7]$ ; $z\in [1,7)$.
Therefore I can't assume $x=y=z=7$ for finding the maximum value of $f(x,y,z)$.
Then what are the minimum and maximum values of $f(x,y,z)$ ?
Is it possible to find the minimum and maximum values of $f(x,y,z)$ ?

Why my question is downvoted without any reason  ? I have included my way. If a question gets downvoted even after showing the research then I can't understand that what is the meaning of making such rules then ?

No, I just assumed that. I also mentioned that it is wrong. Because $x\neq y\neq z$ for this example. For that reason only I wrote $-1<f(x,y,z)<161$  .Also it is $f(x,y,z)$ and not $f(x)$. Because there are $3$ variables

On $D:=[1,7]\times(1,7]\times[1,7)$, $f$ is increasing w.r.t. $x$ and $z$, and decreasing w.r.t. $y$. Therefore, $\sup_{(x,y,z)\in D}f(x,y,z)=f(7,1,7)$ and $\inf_{(x,y,z)\in D}f(x,y,z)=f(1,7,1)$ are not attained on $D$, hence $f$ has no min and no max on $D$.

Can we take the intersection point of $[1,7];(1,7];[1,7)$ ? Which is $(1,7)$ and then try

I don't understand this comment.

No. I mean what is wrong with the intersection ?

$[1,7]\cap(1,7]\cap[1,7)=(1,7)$ is not a "point" but an interval, and I don't know what you intend to "try" with it. What don't you follow in the answer?

Ok. Mam. I understood now. Thank you Anne Madam for helping me.
